# How to wait for a process executed by proc_open() in php?

Tags: php

**please after reading this question , do not say that it is copied.I have already searched on web but none of the solution worked for me.**

**What i am  doing :->**
I am taking a source file (say .c) through php by running apache server on local host.I am saving that file in "/code/" directory and compiling and executing this source file using proc_open() in php.Now i want to wait main php script until the process created by "proc_open()" terminates, so i used "pcntl_waitpid()".But i think there is a problem in using "pcntl_waitpid()" because the script after the "pcntl_waitpid()" is not executing.
Process created by "pcntl_waitpid()" takes input from "/code/input.txt" file and gives output to "/code/output.txt" file, so for redirecting purpose i am using proc_open() , so that i can easily redirect streams.

**My machine configuration:-**
OS -> Ubuntu 12.04 LTs
PHP 5.3.10
APACHE 2.2.22
Running on local host

**Permissions :-**
/code -> 777
Folder where main php file resides -> 777 (I know that 777 is not good due to security reasons , but as i am running script on local server so i have no problem with these permissions.)

**What i want :-**
Can any one tell me any way so that i can stop main php script until the process created by proc-open() terminates or if anyone can tell me other way to meet my requirement of redirection ?

**Here is a part of the code :**

```
$descriptors = array(
            2 => array("pipe","w")
        );




        $process = proc_open($cmd,$descriptors,$pipes,$code);

        sleep(2);

        if(is_resource($process))
        {
            $status = proc_get_status($process);
            $pid = $status ["pid"];

            echo getmypid()."<br />";


            echo $pid;

            if(pcntl_waitpid($pid,$child_status) == -1)
            {
                fclose($pipes[2]);
                proc_close($process);
                exit("Sorry!Unable to compile the source_file.\n");


            }


            while(!file_exists("/code/test"))
            {

                proc_close($process);
                echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]),"\n";
                fclose($pipes[2]);
                exit("Sorry!Unable to compile the source_file.\n");
            }

            echo "Compiled Successfully!\n";
            echo "Running test cases...\n";

            fclose($pipes[2]);

            proc_close($process);

        }
        else
        {
            exit("Sorry!Unable to compile the source_file.\n");
        }
```

**THANK YOU!**

Answer (score 4):

Here's my go at it (reading both stdout and stderr (hopefully) without deadlocks):

```
class ExecResult {
    public $returnValue;
    public $stdoutBuffer;
    public $stderrBuffer;
}

class WtfPhpWhyIHaveToDoEverythingMyself {
    public static function exec($proc, $argv) {
        $cwd = getcwd();
        $env = [];

        $procAndArgv = count($argv) > 0 ?
            $proc . ' ' . implode(' ', self::escapeArgvs($argv)) :
            $proc;

        $pipes = null; // will get filled by proc_open()

        $result = new ExecResult();

        $processHandle = proc_open(
            $procAndArgv,
            [
                0 => ['pipe', 'r'], // read/write is from child process's perspective
                1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
                2 => ['pipe', 'w']
            ],
            $pipes,
            $cwd,
            $env);

        $stdin = $pipes[0];
        $stdout = $pipes[1];
        $stderr = $pipes[2];

        fclose($stdin);

        stream_set_blocking($stdout, false);
        stream_set_blocking($stderr, false);

        $outEof = false;
        $errEof = false;

        do {
            $read = [ $stdout, $stderr ]; // [1]
            $write = null; // [1]
            $except = null; // [1]

            // [1] need to be as variables because only vars can be passed by reference

            stream_select(
                $read,
                $write,
                $except,
                1, // seconds
                0); // microseconds

            $outEof = $outEof || feof($stdout);
            $errEof = $errEof || feof($stderr);

            if (!$outEof) {
                $result->stdoutBuffer .= fgets($stdout);
            }

            if (!$errEof) {
                $result->stderrBuffer .= fgets($stderr);
            }
        } while(!$outEof || !$errEof);

        fclose($stdout);
        fclose($stderr);

        $result->returnValue = proc_close($processHandle);

        return $result;
    }

    private static function escapeArgvs($argv) {
        return array_map(function ($item){
            return escapeshellarg($item);
        }, $argv);
    }
}

$result = WtfPhpWhyIHaveToDoEverythingMyself::exec('/var/www/html/hello.sh', [
    'arg 1',
    'arg 2',
]);

var_dump($result);

/*
object(ExecResult)#1 (3) {
  ["returnValue"]=> int(0)
  ["stdoutBuffer"]=>
  string(45) "var1 = arg 1
var2 = arg 2
"
  ["stderrBuffer"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
*/
```

I am really disappointed that with PHP, you have to write all the plumbing yourself. For example node.js has got your back covered with simple child_process.spawn()

Comment: Thank you! It was hard to find a solution that keeps reading from the streams so the child doesn't block. Most code examples are broken in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use pipes for this problem. pcntl_wait() is Linux only, and it isn't very useful (in my experience) unless your dealing with fork(). Use stream_select for waiting. I'll look further into my old scripts if needed, but it's something like:

```
<?php

$cwd = "/code/";

chmod("/code/test.c",0777);

switch($xtension)
{
    case "c":
        $cmd = "gcc -g test.c -o test -lm ";
    break;
    case "cpp":
        $cmd = "g++ -g test.cpp -o test";
    break;
    case "java":
        $cmd = "javac test.java";
    break;
}

$descriptors = array(   0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
                        1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
                        2 => array('pipe', 'a')  // stderr
);

$process = proc_open($cmd,$descriptors,$pipes,$code);

stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);

if(($error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]) !== false)
{
    // error starting command (error *in* command)
    die($error);

}else
{
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 1);

    /* Prepare the read array */
    $read   = array($pipes[1], $pipes[2]);
    $write  = NULL;
    $except = NULL;
    $tv_sec = 0;      // secs
    $tv_usec = 1000;  // millionths of secs

    if(false === ($rv = stream_select($read, $write, $except, $tv_sec, $tv_usec)))
    {
        die('error in stream_select');

    }else if ($rv > 0)
    {
        foreach($read as $pipe_resource)
        {
            if($pipe_resource == $pipes[1])
            {
                // is stdout

            }else if($pipe_resource == $pipes[2])
            {
                // is stderr
            }
        }

    }else
    {
        // select timed out. plenty of stuff can be done here
    }
}

    // this will be executed after the process terminates
```

There are many ways that you can use this to solve your problem.

First, you can set the timeout in select to zero and it will wait indefinitely. If your executable doesn't use stdout, the stream_select function will block until the pipes are closed when the process terminates.

If your process does use stdout and stderr you can use the select in a loop and check if the pipes are closed each time select returns. This will also allow you to usefully process information from stdout and stderr if needed in the future (json is awesome for this).